# Should the Service Layer access more than 1 Repository?

Tags: php, repository, service-layer

If each service has only one repository, then any data access would have to go through its corresponding service business logic.

For example,

```
$userService->addUser() will call $userRepository->addUser() 
then send an email to the user
```

If the user repository is used by another service other than user service. Then it's possible for another service to call

```
$userRepository->addUser() directly and no email will be sent
```

So to be safe, if another service needs to access the user table, they should use user service and not user repository. A service can depend on multiple services but it should only depend on one repository.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: I wonder why there is no answers. This is a good question

Comment: I have long forgotten the context of this question. 4 years ago, wow!

Comment: Have not you found any reasonable answer? :)

Comment: I think I gave up on php.